# SVN tag in javadoc

Tags: svn, javadoc

I have a question concerning javadoc. It would be nice if there's a possibility to automatically insert the current revision number and the date in all my source files after commit.

With TortoiseCVS I used the following comment:

```
/**
 *  My class.
 *  @version $Revision: $ $Date: $
 */
```

But now I changed to TortoiseSVN and it doesn't work any more. Is this mechanism not supported by Subversion or do I have to restructure the javadoc comment?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure the `$Id$` in your case the `$Revision` Tag in the preferences of SVN within your Eclipse-plugin (if you are using subclipse). http://www.startupcto.com/server-tech/subversion/setting-the-id-tag